# Driver for HelTec E-Ink display

Tags: display, driver, eink

I was given this SPI e-ink / e-paper display from HelTec and am trying to make it work with RPi.

[image: HelTec E-Paper display]
[image: HelTec E-Paper display]

Apparently there’s a [driver for Arduino](https://github.com/HelTecAutomation/e-ink) but I would very much prefer to connect it directly to RPi and program it in Python.

Does anyone know of a driver / library that supports this display?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks very very similar as the Pimoroni one going by the front. Maybe check them out to see if it’s the same controller?  I’d check mine but it’s embedded in the project and not coming out without a hammer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a working driver on https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper —
the file [epd_2in13d_test.py](https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper/blob/master/RaspberryPi&JetsonNano/python/examples/epd_2in13d_test.py) works for my display in B&W. Now I just have to figure out how to draw the colour.

[image: Waveshare logo]